# How to write a POST method result into a file put contents content?

Tags: php, html

I would like to have the the result of an HTML form POST call into the content of another PHP file. 
The goal is to have a redirection page generated dynamically  based on the HTML form values.

```
$redirectionLink = $_POST["redirectionLink"];
$redirectionFileContent =
`
<?php
header("Location:.".'$redirectionLink ');
?>
`;

$otherFileLocation= 'c:\xampp\htdocs\li\something.php';
file_put_contents($otherFileLocation,$redirectionFileContent);
```

I receive the following output when I run the code above:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\shortlink\process.php on line 25
```

I don't know how it would be better. Maybe store it in a variable or write into it as a post call

I'm open to suggestions.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Looks like a simple typo.  Notice the extra `.` and quotes in: `$_POST.'["longlink"]'`  Did you just mean this?:  `'Location:'.$_POST["longlink"]`

Comment: No it does not work because i need it inside the header function and it should be inside quotes in the header function, the whole part

Comment: That description doesn't make much sense.  It's not even really clear what this code is doing.  What do you expect `$redirection` to be?  Is that just a string?  If so then where do you actually execute the redirect?  What specifically are you expecting this to do?  Please clarify the problem.  Currently what you have is clearly a typo because `$_POST` is not a string value.  You'd need to get some value *from* that array, just as the error is telling you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is to simply make a new file that will redirect to the URL received from the POST request, this should do:

```
$longlink = $_POST["longlink"];
$redirection = <<<EOT
<?php
header('Location:{$longlink}');
?>
EOT;
file_put_contents($fileplace, $redirection);
```

Answer (score -1):

This might solve the problem

```
header('Location:.$_POST["longlink"]');
```